# Linking Container in AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I try to setup a little example on AWS Fargate and try to have one application container with one database container there.

The task definition starts both containers, but my app container fails with `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db db:3306`.
Therefore, the database container could not be found by my app container.

Since Fargate does not allow "links" of Docker containers, i'd like to know how they can communicate with each other.
The database container has the name `db` with port `3306` and my app container is configured to use this.

Unfortunately, defining links of containers is not available for Fargate, but only for "oldschool" ECS/EC2.

In a local docker-compose setup it is working this way.

Comment: But what was the change that you did to resolve your issue? Based on the answer you accepted, nothing is required for you to change.

Comment: In my deployed app, I tried to reference the DB as "db:3306". When I deploy the app and db, and reference the db with "localhost:3306" (instead of the service name) it works.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Containers in Fargate tasks share a network namespace, so you don't need to use links at all. You can simply communicate via localhost.

For example, if you have container A running a web server on port 8000, container B could reach it with `curl http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: Thanks, very useful!

Comment: @Noah how would you go with services A and B both listening on 8080 internally, e.g. 2 spring boot projects

Comment: @Noah How do you specify this in cloudFormation?

Comment: @toske You'll need to move one of the services to a different port. Or, in theory, if you want one of them exposed to localhost, and the other exposed to the network, you could explicitly bind one to 127.0.0.1 and the other to a different address.

Comment: @SangamBelose You shouldn't need to specify anything in cloudformation for this. 'awsvpc' mode, whether in ECS or Fargate, implies a shared network namespace (e.g. shared localhost)

Comment: What would need to be done to set up the tasks running on different ports? - would this be done via the Port Mappings "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
on the Task Definition?

Comment: More information from AWS - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/task-networking-in-aws-fargate/

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use AWS Cloud Map service discovery integration with Amazon ECS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-connecting-services.html
With this service you will be able to call other container via DNS name

Answer (score -4):

You can probably set it up so the services can communicate over the public IP address with each other, then secure the ports using a VPC only the services can communicate with themselves on.

Comment: And how do you know the public IP address when building the container? You maybe could do it by assigning an EIP first, then attaching it to Fargate. I don't think you can... Using localhost is much easier!